# Category list ouside Magento Store

Tags: magento2, category-listing

I have a shop in magento in (http://198.143.135.69/) and I'm testing to display the contents of a category outside the magento say in a file on the root of the site (test.php) and hopefully show simple list of products with their name, image, price.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in the root folder as test.php

```
    <?php
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();


   $productId = 100;
   $product = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
   echo $product->getName();
```

As you asked use the above code for testing purpose. Not recommended to use object manager always.

Comment: of course, so I started testing and test well, have a code as well, but intentatr bring the images do not appear : `code`

foreach ($collection as $product){
    echo 'Nombre '.$product->getName().'<br>';
    echo 'SKU '.$product->getSku().'<br>';
    //echo 'image_url'.$product->getImage().'<br>';
}

Comment: $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    foreach($images as $child){ ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $child->getUrl(); ?>" >
<?php } ?>